# How to find what runs every 30 minutes?

Tags: windows-10

Something runs every 30 minutes, immediately closes, makes my screen flicker.

How would I go about figuring out what is (Windows 10)?

I don't see anything useful in the event log.

Comment: Have you check the Task Scheduler?

Comment: @DavidPostill Don't see anything that would match up there.

Comment: How many seconds would you say it appears on the screen before it disappears? Sysinternals/Process-Explorer has a function where you can drag a crosshair over any open window and it will show what process is responsible for that window. If you know when and where on the screen it should appear you could probably time it out where you could capture it real quick and see what process it belongs to.

Comment: @n8te It's just a flash.

Comment: You still might be able to catch it if you have the patience to sit there waiting for it to appear on the screen. It only takes a quick second to capture it in the crosshairs with that process explorer function. It's just point and click.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't identify anything that might be causing this using Task Scheduler, then consider the possibility you may have malware on your system. The fact that it is running on a schedule and you can't identify it with Task Scheduler makes this suspicious. Try using a scanner such as Trend Micro's House Call. If it's possible you have malware on your system, it's good to scan with an anti-virus scan that are you sure is not on a compromised system.

https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/forHome/products/housecall.html.

Answer (score 1):

The file will result very big if you have lot's of process but it may work out of the box in Windows 7 and up.

Make a `.ps1` file for powershell with following code:

```
do {
    ps | select id, name, starttime, path >> c:\youroutput.txt

    sleep 0.5 # You can change this for the amount of time you like, time is in seconds

    }

while($true)
```

Let it run for a while, try it to run as near as the app is bound to run. Once the screen has flickered(you said this behavior) stop the script and check the output, you may need a couple of tries or close the sleep time gap. This small script will give you the id of the process, the name of it, the start time of the app and the path from where it was called from. If you want more information open a powershell prompt and type `ps powershell | select *` should show you the properties of the active powershell object. You can use them in `select` to gather the info you like/need.

Cheers.

Comment: This turned out to be a dead end, but gave me an idea of recording the screen at high framerate. Turns out it was stupid Windows switching background images. For some reason it would open a new window for each monitor on top of everything. I disabled the background slideshow and the flickering is gone.